# How to select objects based on their property which is not string type?

Tags: powershell

For example,

```
PS C:\Users\lgd> Get-PSDrive

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                                                                       CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                                                                                       ---------------
Alias                                  Alias
C                  86.42         32.70 FileSystem    C:\                                                                                                                                              Users\lgd
Cert                                   Certificate   \
E                                      FileSystem    E:\
Env                                    Environment
F                  14.49         14.17 FileSystem    F:\
Function                               Function
HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Temp               86.42         32.70 FileSystem    C:\Users\lgd\AppData\Local\Temp\
Variable                               Variable
WSMan                                  WSMan
```

and I would like to output the rows in which the Provider is `FileSystem`, but

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object Provider -eq "FileSystem"
```

doesn't work because the type of `Provider` property is not string.
So How to do to output my expected ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_.Provider` returns an instance of [`ProviderInfo` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.providerinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) which has a [`Name` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.providerinfo.name?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_ProviderInfo_Name) which you can use to get the name of the provider *as a string*.

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object { $_.Provider.Name -eq "FileSystem" }
```